# how to create duplicate field in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2016

Hi programmer I am beginner in ms access I need help.
Ok, I have questions about ms access database form
I create daily sales entry database and I am trying to do somethings like.
I have sales table and there is one field is date and other one is Transaction no and I create one sales entry form and there is two above field and I want to enter date in date field then automatically filled transaction Id as like format yyyymm. and this one is each month for same one.

Example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzPRG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHcyt.png)

i am trying this one my sales entry database